# симулятор запускается с черным экраном после переустановки XCode 10

Tags: ios, xcode

при запуске рабочего приложения симуляторы запускаются с черным экраном. удаление и чистка хвостов, а так же установка XCode 9 не помогла.
у кого-то был подобный опыт?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить `defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint 3` в Терминале ([источник](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103653)).
Обратите внимание, что это заставит симулятор использовать OpenGL вместо Metal, поэтому Вы можете перезапустить его с нуля, как только это будет исправлено.